# Perfect infinitive in the Future

Tags: perfect-constructions

Which is correct?:

> I will have had enough time to come by Monday
>
> I will have had enough time to have come by Monday
>
> I will have enough time to have come by Monday

If all of them are correct, please, explain the every sentence's meaning to me

Comment: What are you trying to say? In what sense do you require time in order to come (or go) somewhere by Monday?

Comment: We can say: "I will have come by Monday". It's Future Pefect - an action before some moment in the future. But what if we have not 1 action (to come) but 2 (will want to come, will have enough time to come, will ask to come etc.". What then? Which one should be in Perfect?

Comment: Sentence 3 is a no-go. Also, to come by [your house, your office, etc.] so two bys.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know how to answer your question because the constructions you suggest are all highly unusual.

Imagine that a friend has asked you to assist him with a task. You might respond in any of the following ways.

> I don't have time this week but I will be able to help you next week.
>   I will have finished my work by Friday and will be able to come on Monday.
>   I will have had enough of computing by the weekend and will be able to come on Monday.
>   I will have found a gap in my schedule to come by Monday.

But none of your suggestions is idiomatic and all would puzzle a native English speaker.

Comment: I think one and two are okay. I will have had enough time to come by [your house] by Monday.

Comment: But how can you say "to come by Monday". Shouldn't it always be "perfect tense" with the periods be which something will have happened?
WHat is the difference then between: "I will have found a gap in my schedule to come by Monday." AND "I will have found a gap in my schedule to have come by Monday?